# How to use json subitems in Material Table with sorting

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a problem with Angular Material table with sorting headers.
As far as I use first level items from my json file, everything working fine.But when I need to use subitem sorting not working.

I'm using Wordpress REST API and it returns me something like this:

```
{
  "id": 1361,
  "name": "Item1",
  "price": "15355",
  "weight": "482",
  "dimensions": {
      "length": 1000,
      "width": 550,
      "height": "132"
  }
},
{
  "id": 1362,
  "name": "Item2",
  "price": "12456",
  "weight": "352",
  "dimensions": {
      "length": "610",
      "width": "375",
      "height": "120"
  }
}
```

I'm using it in Material Table and columns like: ID, name, price and weight works correctly.
Unfortunately items inside "dimensions" not.

In .ts file every column has proper name:

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'name', 'price', 'weight', 'length', 'width', 'height'];
```

And in html each column looks like this:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="length">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Length </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.dimensions.length}} cm</td>
</ng-container>
```

I thought maybe name of the column is not right and I changed it to:

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'name', 'price', 'weight', 'dimensions.length', 'width', 'height'];
```

And html:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="dimensions.length">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Length </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.dimensions.length}} cm</td>
</ng-container>
```

But it still not sorting.

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sort does NOT work by itself. In typescript define

```
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
@ViewChild(MatTable) table: MatTable<any>;
private unsubscribe: Subject<void> = new Subject();

ngAfterViewInit() {
 this.sort.sortChange.pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe)).
      subscribe(() => this.sortTable());
}

private sortTable() {
// Use this.sort.active (column name, e.g. 'width', this.sort.direction (string 'asc' or 'desc') 
// to sort the array of your items and call
 this.table.renderRows();
}

ngOnDestroy() {
   this.unsubscribe.next();
   this.unsubscribe.complete();
}
```

So you get a reference to `MatSort` and just sort the items yourself by subscribing to the changes + rendering rows of the table. Note the usage of `unsubscribe` - this is a standard pattern to prevent leakage of memory because of subscriptions to observables. Make your `TS` to `implement AfterViewInit, OnDestroy` to use `ngAfterViewInit` and `ngOnDestroy`